# VueJS toggle true/false for elements in a loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

So i am using `v-for` to render a list of elements. The text is rendered inside a v-chip. The chip has an avatar which holds the icon and a span which hold the text. There is a `prop : chipToggle`  set on `span` which hides/shows it. What i am trying to do is `onClick` set the selected to `true` and the other to `false`. Right now both get set to true/false simultaneously.

This is sample [pen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/Yzyqomz)

This is my sample code:-

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      inputValue: "",
      myArray: [],
      showText: true,
      selected: "",
      chipToggle: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    createArray() {
      this.myArray.unshift(this.inputValue);
      this.inputValue = "";
      console.log(this.myArray);
    },
    clear() {
      this.inputValue = "";
      this.myArray = [];
      console.log(this.myArray);
    },
    onSelect(item) {
      console.log((this.selected = item));
    },
    toggleDisplay(item) {
      this.onSelect();
      this.chipToggle = !this.chipToggle;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-layout justify-center>
      <v-flex xs6>
        <v-text-field v-model="inputValue">
        </v-text-field>
        <v-btn :disabled="inputValue === ''" @click="createArray">Click Me</v-btn>
        <v-btn @click="clear">Clear</v-btn>
        <v-layout row v-if="myArray.length > 0">
          <v-flex v-for="(item,i) in myArray">
            <v-chip @click="onSelect(item)">
              <v-avatar>
                <v-icon @click="toggleDisplay(item)">account_circle</v-icon>
              </v-avatar>
              <span v-if="chipToggle">{{item}}</span>
            </v-chip>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

So essentially whichever i select should be set to true and the other(s) to be set to false. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your array, use a data structure like `{ value: this.inputValue, toggled: true }` where each element stores its own toggled value. See below code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      inputValue: "",
      myArray: [],
      showText: true,
      selected: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    createArray() {
      this.myArray.unshift({ value: this.inputValue, toggled: false });
      this.inputValue = "";
      console.log(this.myArray);
    },
    clear() {
      this.inputValue = "";
      this.myArray = [];
      console.log(this.myArray);
    },
    onSelect(item) {
      this.selected = item;
    },
    toggleDisplay(item) {
      this.myArray.forEach(el => el.toggled = false);
      item.toggled = true;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-layout justify-center>
      <v-flex xs6>
        <v-text-field v-model="inputValue">
        </v-text-field>
        <v-btn :disabled="inputValue === ''" @click="createArray">Click Me</v-btn>
        <v-btn @click="clear">Clear</v-btn>
        <v-layout row v-if="myArray.length > 0">
          <v-flex v-for="(item,i) in myArray">
            <v-chip @click="onSelect(item)">
              <v-avatar>
                <v-icon @click="toggleDisplay(item)">account_circle</v-icon>
              </v-avatar>
              <span v-if="item.toggled">{{item.value}}</span>
            </v-chip>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Ayy!!! Thanks for the help. I was thinking that each element would need it's own toggle but wasn't sure how to do it. Thank You so much!! Accepting the answer as soon as the timer is over.

Comment: @TreeHuggerRick Glad to help..yes in such scenarios, an array of objects serves best. Do accept :)

Comment: Oh wait. It's not quite there yet. So if i set one of the chips to true, i want the other to change to false as well.

Comment: So one is true, the others are false.

Comment: @TreeHuggerRick I changed some logic inside the `toggleDisplay` function